# What is the best approach to merge a list of really big lists in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, sorting, merge, redis, heapsort

I am making an api crawler app in NodeJS, that makes parallel calls to several rest api at the same time.  Each of these rest api calls return a sorted list of objects.  These lists can be huge.  Now I have to merge them to make a big sorted list and return this as my response.

After each api call is complete, I store the result in redis and when all are done I merge using a heap sort algorithm. Is this the best way in regards to space and time efficiency?

Another way I though I could do this was to simply do the merge algorithm from merge sort.  What is best approach?

Comment: If you're using redis you should be able to simply use a sorted set.  zadd the objects with their sort scores and zrange to retrieve them sorted.

Answer (score 0):

> Merge sorted arrays method  (O(n1 + n2) Time and O(n1 + n2) Extra
>   Space)

The idea is to use Merge function of Merge sort.

- Create an array arr3[] of size n1 + n2.
- Simultaneously traverse    arr1[] and arr2[].
- Pick smaller of current elements in arr1[] and arr2[], copy this
  smaller element to next position in arr3[] and move ahead in arr3[]
  and the array whose element is picked.
- If there are are remaining elements in arr1[] or arr2[], copy them
  also in arr3[].

Answer (score -1):

> I see you can use Promise Object ..

```
var promiseApi1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  // call api1 and resolve result ..
  resolve(result);
});

var promiseApi2 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  // call api2 and resolve result ..
  resolve(result);
});

Promise.all([promiseApi1,promiseApi2]).then(values=>{
    // values is array of all results will back from all apis
    // merge values here ..
});
```

Comment: I am already doing this in code, my question concerns the actual merge.